# Div fixa esconder quando chegar em outra div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Olá,

Estou tentando implementar esta ideia ao meu projeto:

https://jsfiddle.net/dx2dsta9/

```
function removerSetas() {
    var topo = $(window).scrollTop(),
        alvo = $("#alvo").offset().top,
      setas = $(".left, .right");

  if ( topo > alvo ) {
    setas.addClass("hide");
  } else {
    setas.removeClass("hide");
  }
}

$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(removerSetas);
  removerSetas();
});
```

Quando chegar em uma div com o `id="alvo"` é adicionada a `classe="hide"` nas setas, vendo no console realmente adiciona corretamente quando chega no `id="alvo"`

Na estrutura do meu projeto não esta funcionando corretamente, esse é o meu código:

http://jsfiddle.net/p4ygLp6y/embedded/result/

A classe hide esta sendo adicionada pelo js antes de chegar no id=alvo. As divs sem conteudo deixei assim para ser possivel ver apenas a estrutura

Agradeço ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Você deve indicar que as setas só devem sumir só quando o meio do elemento for alcançado, para isso é necessário obter a altura do elemento e dividí-la por 2

```js
function removerSetas() {
 var topo = $(window).scrollTop(),
    alvo = $("#alvo").offset().top,
      alvoHeight = $("#alvo").height()
      setas = $(".left, .right");
      
  if ( topo > alvo + (alvoHeight / 2) ) {
   setas.addClass("hide");
  } else {
   setas.removeClass("hide");
  }
}

$(function() {
 $(window).scroll(removerSetas);
  removerSetas();
});
```

Segue o link do fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dx2dsta9/1/

Comment: Olá @Eriky, obrigada pela resposta, não houve alteração implementando sua sugestão: http://jsfiddle.net/p4ygLp6y/1/embedded/result/

Comment: o div com id "alvo" está solto na página, acho que para conseguir efeito que você deseja terá que colocar o contéudo que está após a div  "alvo" dentro dela.

Comment: Já tinha tentado mesmo assim não mudou, tentei no fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p4ygLp6y/2/ é la avança um pouco mas some antes do id=alvo também